# Issue with appengine deferred tasks, execution throws unknown error

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, deferred-execution

I have task deferred in appengine python its a simple call with all task_info strings, list of strings. It works well for any no of tasks.

```
               deferred.defer(fetch_service, 
                              _queue = "queue_name",
                              _countdown = task_counter * 4,
                              **task_info  )
```

I observed a weird behaviour, when I access some endpoints or UI in different URL or different modules, this deferred calls start to fail. Every differed call throws same issue.

```
File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/deferred/deferred.py", line 145, in run
    raise PermanentTaskFailure(e)
PermanentTaskFailure: None.fetch_service forbidden in unpickling
```

Looking for any help, or others who faced same issue.

Answer (score 4):

This problem is specific to the [GAE python scaffold](https://github.com/google/gae-secure-scaffold-python) provided by Google. There's a whitelist of methods that are allowed to be pickled.

If you add your `fetch_service` method to the `_PICKLE_CLASS_WHITELIST` in `base/api_fixers.py` list, it will work.

Answer (score 1):

The `PermanentTaskFailure` exception [indicates](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/refdocs/google.appengine.ext.deferred.deferred#google.appengine.ext.deferred.deferred.PermanentTaskFailure) that a task failed, and will never succeed.

This typically means some invalid condition is encountered when the GAE infra attempts to schedule the task.

The `None.fetch_service` string in the error message points to an invalid reference: `None` doesn't have a `fetch_service` attribute.

This could indicate the task execution is attempted in a module which doesn't have access to the `fetch_service` object. I'd check the imports in the module displaying the error.